# Convert string representation of a nameless tuple, to tuple

Tags: ios, swift, tuples

I know this might be easy, but I am very new to `Swift` and need all the help I can get.

I have a string that when printed shows, `"("Example 1", "Example 2")"`
Now if I assign that to a variable, I can't call individual elements in the `tuple`, as it is clearly not a `tuple`.

Now I would like to know if there is a way to convert into a `tuple`, perhaps with `JSONSerialization`?

I tried 
`let array = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! Array<Any>`,
 and that works with a string of `"["Example 1", "Example 2"]"`, but not a tuple, I tried changing the `[]` in `options:` to `()`, but that did not work.

Comment: You are trying to make a tuple from array? hard to understand what you need

Comment: I have a string, which without the first `"` and the last `"`, it would be a tuple, but you cannot get rid of those with a simple string replace. I want to change `"("Example 1", "Example 2")"` -> `("Example 1", "Example 2")`

Comment: So basically you are trying to make a tuple from a string? `"("Example 1", "Example 2")"` to a tuple with `"Example 1"` and `"Example 2"`?

Comment: Where does the string come from? Why is the tuple stored like that? Can the individual strings contain parentheses, commas or quotations marks? Did you consider to use a different format (like JSON)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

base on what i understand you want to create a tuple out of a string, which the string looks kinda like a tuple as well. so what you need to do is extract values within this string and create a tuple.

here is simple solution if you are always sure the format is the same

```
func extractTuple(_ string: String) -> (String,String) {
     //removes " and ( and ) from the string to create "Example 1, Example 2"
    let pureValue = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "", options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil).replacingOccurrences(of: "(", with: "", options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil).replacingOccurrences(of: ")", with: "", options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil)

    let array = pureValue.components(separatedBy: ", ")
    return (array[0], array[1])
}
```

then you can use it like this

```
let string = "(\"Example 1\", \"Example 2\")"
let result = extractTuple(string)
print(result)
```

Comment: What if the strings themselves contain parentheses or commas? – Try it with `let string = "(\"A(B)C\", \"D, E\")"`

Comment: Yes this works, but what if the string contains a comma?